# Sample Winform implemented on both MVC and MVP

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller, mvp

I already searched the net, but I can't find a sample application that is implemented using both [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [MVP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter). This is for comparison, I'm still confused about the difference of the two patterns. A simple data entry form will do.

Thanks.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) and [this document](http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had that question before, and the following link answered my question.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288928/Differences-between-MVC-and-MVP-for-Beginners

Hopefully that answers yours as well.